# Calculating roll from yaw, pitch, and up vector

Tags: math, opengl, vector, 3d

If I have a camera's yaw, pitch, and up vector (always [0,1,0] in my case), what's the best way to calculate the corresponding roll?

Comment: I don't understand, if the up vector is [0,1,0], doesn't that by definition mean there is no pitch or roll?

Answer (score 0):

When a camera's up vector is (0,1,0), the effect is to lock its yaw to 0 degrees.